# Get data from Inherit Model Django

Tags: python, django, database, oop, inheritance

Im working in my Python Django ecommerce project.Now i have 2 classes Item and BookItem :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug         = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    description  = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    price        = models.IntegerField()
    images       = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/products')
    stock        = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    category     = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('item_detail',args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])

    

class BookItem(Item):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get BookItem data from the class Item.Anyone knows how to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting but Item is an abstract model that allows BookItem and LaptopItem to benefit from shared functionalities. So, I do not think that's possible from the way you want  to do this. And anyways, following he laws of class inheritance in Python, subclasses inherit from the superclass. A superclass cannot logically inherit from it's subclass unless you do some type of manipulation e.g. using metaclass

Answer (score 0):

**Get Book data for all Items**

```
Item.objects.all().values(
  "book__book_name",
  "book__import_price",
# "class_name__field_name", structure of the query
)
```

**To filter Item data using Book fields
[filter Items where book name is 'bookname']**

```
Item.objects.filter(book__book_name="bookname")
```